# How to display a custom parameter value in the PCB footprint of my Altium component?

Tags: pcb-design, altium, footprint

Suppose my component has a string-valued parameter named "Label". I'd like the PCB footprint for this component to automatically display whatever value was set for this parameter in the schematic view.

I've tried placing a text component with the value ".Label", and I've enabled "Convert special strings" in the PCB view configuration, but the text still shows as just ".Label".

Can I somehow get it to show the value of the "Label" parameter as set (and displayed) in the schematic view?

Comment: Not all schematic properties propagate to the PCB. I don't think your label property is propagating. The only property I know that does propagate is the "comment." That is automatically pulled from the "value" property of the schematic symbol. You migth be able to tell Altium to use your label property for "comment" when exporting netlist to PCB. You should try asking altium.

Comment: A work around might be to use a project parameter

Comment: Have you put the string on the desired layer with the .Label form in the PCB footprint?

Comment: @LukeGary is right, if you want special string to work for components you have to add it to the component on some layer. You can't just add a text and associate it with a component.

Answer (score 8):

There is one way, some kind of workaround. But you have to give up the **Component's comment field** because we will use this to show a custom parameter on the PCB along with the footprint.

---

1. Add your new parameter and set it visible. Under **Properties** set the **Default Comment** to your custom parameter and do not check the **Visible** box.

   [image]

---

2. Add your component to the schematic and set a value for the custom parameter.

   [image]

---

3. In PCBdoc, right-click on the footprint and in **Component Actions** select **Show Comment**.

   [image]

---

4. Now your custom parameter is visible under the footprint in the PCBdoc.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the value is properly formatting:
Hit '3' to enter 3D viewing mode and you should be able to see the strings properly rendered. They also will show up if you do a Composite drawing printout.